# I trying to have a button that shows and hidden my image

Tags: javascript, image, show-hide

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Face</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function myFunction(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.visibility == "visible")
         e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       else
          e.style.visibility = 'visibile';
    }



</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="position: relative; visibility: visible;">
<img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"
          alt="Pumpkins" id="Pum"/>
<button onclick="myFunction('Pum')">Face</button>
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

I trying to have a button that shows/hidden my image. I don't understand what I am doing wrong . I am getting an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of null". How do I fix my error and make my program work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a typo in the code

```
function myFunction(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.visibility == "visible")
         e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       else
          e.style.visibility = 'visible'; // <-------- SHOULD BE 'visible', was 'visibile'
    }
```

This should fix your problem.